# Loading css stylesheets inside <noscript> tags with Flask

Tags: css, html, flask

I'm trying to adapt some templates from http://html5up.net to work with Flask. The static HTML pages load fine with a directory structure

```
/website
  /css
  /js
  /images
  index.html
```

But for Flask it has to be

```
/website
    /templates
        index.html
    /static
        /css
        /js
        /images
```

Adding `/static` before the javascript and image files works fine, and they display as expected. However, the links to the css files are inside `<noscript>` tags, and I can't get the main html page to find them. I've tried absolute and relative addressing, and moving the stylesheets to different places in the directory structure, but no luck. I just get an ugly page with no css styling.

If I remove the  tags, then it loads fine for desktop use, but the page is then no longer adapts when viewed with a tablet or phone.

An excerpt from the original header:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
```

And what I would expect to work, but doesn't

```
<head>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/config.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="/static/js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
```

-EDIT-

The contents of config.js

```
window._skel_config = {
    preset: 'standard',
    prefix: 'css/style',
    resetCSS: true,
    breakpoints: {
        '1000px': {
            grid: {
                gutters: 25
            }
        }
    }
};

window._skel_panels_config = {
    preset: 'standard'
};
```

Comment: The noscript tag is only executed when JS is disabled. It sounds like the javascript is including CSS files and the noscript tag is there to include the CSS files in case JS is disabled. Check config.js to see if it does anything with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for comment - I've added the contents of the config file. I don't see anything which would break because of the structure change.

Comment: You probably need to change `prefix: 'css/style'` to `prefix: '/static/css/style'` in config.js

Answer (score -1):

```
Try This:

<head>
        <script src="..\static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="..\static/js/config.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\static/css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\static/css/style-desktop.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\static/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="..\static/js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have try to modification contents config.js file with this :

```
window._skel_config = {
    preset: 'standard',
    prefix: 'http://website/static/css/style',
    resetCSS: true
};

window._skel_panels_config = {
    preset: 'standard'
};
```